# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Multi Language Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am having trouble making my application multi-language. I tried the old way with resources (resx files) but it seems they are missing from ASP.NET 5, can you please help me with some guidance or a link to read about this? I searched the web for an article or something but I found nothing. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean they are missing. You can find resource file under properties section.

Comment: by missing I mean I can not add new item -> resx file, under Properties section I have AppSettings with only one property SiteTitle and it is returning the value from AppSettings (config.json). I don't see how I can use these config files. Give me a hint please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from statements made in the asp.net community standups on Scott Hanselman's youtube page I think localization won't be available until beta6 or beta7

you might be able to create resx files in your project now but you won't be able to use them yet

I'm in the same boat with my own project and waiting to tackle localization once it is possible

Comment: I think beta6 will ship by the end of this month, but if I remember correctly I think it will be beta7 before localization is ready. my guess is beta7 will ship 20-30 days after beta6 ships. RC is targeted for release in mid November so definitely by then all the expected features should be working

Answer (score 3):

Resource file are still available with Asp.Net 5 application. You need to right click in the **Solution Explorer** the project (or folder inside a project) and select **Add New Item**. From there you can get under **Visual C#** > **General** > **Resources File**.

Comment: but can they be used if code for it is not yet there?